# BufferedReader won't read after first line

Tags: java, file, loops, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I have 4 text files a.txt,b.txt,c.txt and c.txt 
I have a codition to fetch line from a.txt and if the condition follows then I have another  condition to fetch further from either b,c or d (which ever follows the condition)

```
import java.io.*; 
public class Scholarship { 
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{

        FileInputStream fstream1 = new  FileInputStream("a.txt"); 
        FileInputStream fstream2 = new  FileInputStream("b.txt"); 
        FileInputStream fstream3 = new  FileInputStream("c.txt"); 
        FileInputStream fstream4 = new  FileInputStream("d.txt");       
             DataInputStream in1 = new DataInputStream(fstream1);
             DataInputStream in2 = new DataInputStream(fstream2);
             DataInputStream in3 = new DataInputStream(fstream3);
             DataInputStream in4 = new DataInputStream(fstream4);
              BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in1));
              BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in2));
              BufferedReader br3 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in3));
              BufferedReader br4 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in4));

        String strLine1=null;
        String strLine2=null;
        String strLine3=null;
        String strLine4=null;

        while((strLine1 = br1.readLine()) != null){

           String[] column1 = strLine1.split("\\|");

           if(Integer.parseInt(column1[1])<5000) {   

                while((strLine2 = br2.readLine())!=null){
                   String[] column2 = strLine2.split("\\|");
                   if(  (column1[0].equals(column2[0]))&&(column2[2].equals("mumbai"))&&( (column2[3].equals("C"))||(column2[3].equals("D")) ) ){   
                     System.out.println(strLine2);

                   }//if ends                   
                }//while ends 

                while((strLine3 = br3.readLine())!=null){
                   String[] column3 = strLine3.split("\\|");
                   if(  (column1[0].equals(column3[0]))&&(column3[2].equals("mumbai"))&&( (column3[3].equals("C"))||(column3[3].equals("D")) ) ){   
                     System.out.println(strLine3);

                   }//if ends                   
                }//while ends 

                while((strLine4 = br4.readLine())!=null){
                   String[] column4 = strLine4.split("\\|");
                   if(  (column1[0].equals(column4[0]))&&(column4[2].equals("mumbai"))&&( (column4[3].equals("C"))||(column4[3].equals("D")) ) ){   
                     System.out.println(strLine4);

                   }//if ends                   
                }//while ends   


             }//if ends          
         }//while ends       

        in1.close();
        in2.close();
        in3.close();
        in4.close();
    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

The Outer loop is for a.txt and inner 3 loops for b,c and d. The code only prints when first condition is satisfied in a.txt. IT'S NOT CHECKING for furthur lines in a.txt. I have tried it with Scanner method, but same problem is there.

Comment: _Can you please post content of  your `a.txt`?_

Comment: Can you try to create the readers like this: `BufferedReader br1 = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("a.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `DataInputStream` unless you intentionally want to read primitive Java data types (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html).

You could instantiate the `BufferedReader` reader either like this:

```
BufferedReader br1 = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("a.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

or traditionally like this:

```
BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("a.txt"));
```

At the end you can close all the BufferedReaders. They will implicitly cascade close all their containing streams.

Comment: You can simply use `BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("a.txt"));`